# Assumption of Positive Dielectric Value in Derivation of Dipole Field Around a Spherical Dielectric? Implications for Plasmonics

Tags: electromagnetism

I am going through the solutions to Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates.  In particular the boundary value problem of a dielectric sphere of radius $a$ and permittivity $\epsilon$ which has a constant electric field $\mathbf{E} = E_{0}\mathbf{z}$ applied to it.  The outer medium has permittivity $\epsilon_{m}$. I realise this is mainly textbook stuff, however on a certain step I am having trouble with the logic applied, and find that it is not well explained in any textbooks.  Starting from the general solution to Laplace's equation for azimuthally invariant problems I will try and solve the boundary value problem to try and show what I mean. To those familiar with this derivation please skip down to the bottom.

---

The general solution for the potential $\nabla^{2}{U} = 0$ in spherical coordinates for azimuthal symmetry is:

$U(r,\theta) = \sum^{\infty}_{l=0} [A_{l}r^{l}+B_{l}r^{-(l+1)}]P_{l}(cos\theta)$

For the dielectric sphere we must distinguish between the potential inside and outside the sphere $U_{in}$ and $U_{out}$.  Since we require a finite potential at the origin we can already simplify $U_{in}$

$U_{in}(r,\theta) = \sum^{\infty}_{l=0}A_{l}r^{l}P_{l}(cos\theta)$
Also since the potential should converge to that of the applied field for $r\rightarrow\infty$, one of the coefficients for $U_{out}$ is also determined, $A^{out}_{1} = -E_{0}rP_{1}(\cos\theta)$, $A_{l} = 0 l\neq1$  Therefore before applying the boundary conditions we have:

$U_{in}(r,\theta) = \sum^{\infty}_{l=0} A_{l}r^{l}P_{l}(cos\theta)$

$U_{out}(r,\theta) = -E_{0}rP_{1}(\cos\theta) + \sum^{\infty}_{l=0} B_{l}r^{-(l+1)}P_{l}(cos\theta)$

The boundary conditions are the continuity of the tangential E field and the normal D field at the sphere boundary.  In terms of the potential this gives:

$\sum^{\infty}_{l=0} {A_{l}a^{l}\frac{{\partial}P_{l}(cos\theta)}{\partial\theta}} = -E_{0}a\frac{{\partial}P_{1}(\cos\theta)}{\partial\theta} + \sum^{\infty}_{l=0} B_{l}a^{-(l+1)}\frac{{\partial}P_{l}(\cos\theta)}{\partial\theta}$

$-\epsilon\sum^{\infty}_{l=0} {A_{l}la^{l-1}P_{l}(cos\theta)} = -\epsilon_{m}\left\{ -E_{0}P_{1}(\cos\theta) - \sum^{\infty}_{l=0} B_{l}(l+1)a^{-(l+2)}P_{l}(\cos\theta) \right\}$
By matching the orders of the Legendre functions we obtain conditions for $A_{l}$ and $B_{l}$
For $l = 1$:

$A_{1}a = B_{1}a^{-2}-E_{0}a$ and $-{\epsilon}A_{1} = -\epsilon_{m}\left\{-B_{1}2a^{-3}+E_{0}\right\}$

Which can be solved to produce

$A_{1} = \frac{3\epsilon_{m}}{\epsilon+2\epsilon_{m}}E_{0}$ and $B_{1} = \frac{\epsilon-\epsilon_{m}}{\epsilon+2\epsilon_{m}}E_{0}a^{3}$

Now comes my problem with dealing with the rest of the terms.  The equations read:

$A_{l}a^{l} = B_{l}a^{-(l+1)}$ and $-{\epsilon}A_{l}la^{l-1} = \epsilon_{m}B_{l}(l+1)a^{-(l+2)}$

Which together lead to the condition:

$A_{l} [{\epsilon}l + \epsilon_{m}(l+1)] = 0$

---

Here is my question: based on the above condition all textbooks assume that $A_{l}$ (and by extension $B_{l}$) are zero for $l\neq1$, since the term in brackets cannot be zero for $l\geq 0$. Which is fine if we consider both the sphere and the exterior to be dielectrics.

However what happens if we assume that the sphere is a metal at optical frequencies which has a negative permittivity $\epsilon <1$ This condition could then be satisfied with any value of $A_{l}$ and $B_{l}$ which makes no sense to me. Can someone please tell me, was there an implicit assumption somewhere that $\epsilon>1$ which I haven't picked up on, or is there some other fundamental error I am making?

The reason I ask about metals is that the conditions for $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ are used for metallic spheres in plasmonics, where $\epsilon$ is quite happily set to a negative number resulting a in resonance in the the values of $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$

Thanks very much for taking the time to read my question.